# Why can't I pass this method directly into the constructor, why do I need to use a lambda?

Tags: kotlin

I just started to learn Kotlin yesterday, so brace yourself for a potentially stupid question.

```
class MyCustomViewAdapter(private val callback: (position: Int) -> Unit) : RecyclerView.Adapter<MyCustomViewHolder>() {
    ...
}
```

When I try to initialize this class, I need to pass in a callback parameter to receive events.

```
MyCustomViewAdapter({ position -> onClickFlowerCallback(position)}) // this works

MyCustomViewAdapter(onClickFlowerCallback) // this doesn't work?

private fun onClickFlowerCallback(position: Int) {
    println("We have successfully received click from position #" + position.toString())
}
```

Can someone enlighten me to why this is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you want to do is pass a [method reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reflection.html#function-references) — you just need the right syntax, which is `::onClickFlowerCallback`.

Similarly, to call `someObject.onClickFlowerCallback`, you'd pass `someObject::onClickFlowerCallback`.

You can also pass a reference to a top-level function, local function, extension function, constructor, member property, top-level property, or extension property using the same syntax. See [the docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/lambdas.html#instantiating-a-function-type) for more.